# Extract line containing search string using regex

Tags: regex

String =

```
"A Borrower (or the Parent) may not deliver a Request if as a result of the proposed Utility:
[15] or more Term Loans [(other than Inc Loans)] would be outstanding; [or]
[10] or more Utilisations would be outstanding[; or
[5 ] or more Loans would be outstanding]."

Output = "[15] or more Term Loans [(other than Inc Loans)] would be outstanding;"
```

Regex Pattern I'm Trying:

```
'(.*other than Inc Loans.*)'
```

This returns me the whole STRING, I just need that one line. Dont know what wrong im doing with regex

Code in Asp.net

```
string regularExpressionPattern = RegExPattern.ToString();
string inputText = FinalPara.ToString();
Regex re = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern);
foreach (Match m in re.Matches(FinalPara))
{
    Response.Write("Regex Values is :" + m.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the line breaks are there in the original string? Are they CRLFs or just CRs? Try `([^\r\n]*other than Inc Loans[^\r\n]*)` with your current code (although you do not need the capturing group here, you may access the match using `m.Value`).

Comment: Also, why regex? Try `var result = inputText.Split(new[] {"\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => x.Contains("other than Inc Loans")).FirstOrDefault()`. See [demo](https://ideone.com/VMEIQl). Remove `.FirstOrDefault()` to get all lines containing the text you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Can you add this as answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split the text with CR and LFs and only grab those that contain your required text value using mere LINQ and `String.Contains`:

```
var results = inputText.Split(new[] {"\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => x.Contains("other than Inc Loans"));
```

To get the first "match", use `.FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var result = inputText.Split(new[] {"\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => x.Contains("other than Inc Loans")).FirstOrDefault();
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/VMEIQl).

**Details**

- `.Split(new[] {"\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` - splits into lines
- `.Where(x => x.Contains("other than Inc Loans"))` - extracts items that contain specific text.

If you plan to keep to regex, make sure you match neither LF nor CR chars. The pattern should look like `[^\r\n]*other than Inc Loans[^\r\n]*` (where `[^\r\n]` matches any char but CR and LF chars) and after you get a match, access the match value via `m.Value`.